# Rails models : SQL OR AND keywords

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, models

I use rails and I want a request likes that:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 5 AND 
active = true AND 
(current_state = 0 OR current_state = 1)
```

I write something likes that:

```
Event.where(id:5).where(active:true).or(Event.where(current_state:)).or
(Event.where(current_state: 1))
```

But when I do that, I have this request:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 5 AND 
active = true AND 
current_state = 0 OR current_state = 1
```

How can I have parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Event.where('WHERE id = ? AND active = ? AND (current_state = ? OR current_state = ?)', 5, true, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks ! And for a LIKE, can i do `Event.where("city LIKE :city1", {city1: "%#{params[:party][:city]}%"})` ?

Comment: i am not sure for your method, but it will be work `Event.where("city LIKE :? ",  "%#{params[:party][:city]}%")`